# what wrong with my e-mail workflow

Tags: javascript, php

The variable-free php version worked. But with the variables there is trouble, so the problem should be with the php file:

IS THIS CORRECT?

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['q'];
$content=$_GET['r'];
$to      = 'mail@gmail.com';
$subject = $name;
$message = $content;
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: jcblaub@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

---

the html-form - problem should not be here

```
<form action="/action_page.php" class="header">
    <label for="fname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Name ...">

    <label for="lname">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="E-Mail ...">

    <label for="country">Betreff - Optional</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="usa">-</option>
        <option value="australia">Reservierung</option>
        <option value="canada">Reperatur</option>
        <option value="usa">Fahrrad-Auswahl</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Nachricht</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Nachricht ..." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

my JS File - problem should also not be here

ajax call

```
function send(str, co) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert('Ihre Nachricht wurde verschickt!');
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","mail.php?q="+str + "&r=" + co ,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is action_page.php at the same level as mail.php?

Comment: The first thing that's wrong with it is that it is hard to read due to the lack of indenting. Help us to help you by formatting your code to make it readable.

Comment: there is no action_page.php that's just what error message calls the missing file.

Comment: You don't show your HTML, but is the `'#submit'` button inside a form element that has `action="action_page.php"`?

Comment: This is just for testing right? And you are going to validate the given input!?

Comment: I am testin it as it is. there are no variables in the php, so it should work. Or what do you mean by validating?

Comment: I was refering to the TEST section below, cause clearly the rest is not wokring.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your php script

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Run this php code in a separate file. It will not produce error. Error you are getting from other part of code.

Comment: I got it to work, now there is just sth wrong with the variables.